# Behave framework .ini file usage

Tags: config, bdd, gherkin, python-behave

In my .ini file I have

```
[behave]
format=rerun
outfiles=rerun_failing.features
```

So I want to use "rerun_failing.features" file for storing scenarios that fail.
However when I run '--steps-catalog' command, it also stores that catalog to the same file. Why is that?

How to make set up two separate files for commands '--rerun' and '--steps-catalog'?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use `behave --dry-run -f steps.catalog ...` instead. The output of the steps.catalog formatter is written to stdout, not the "rerun-outputfile".